# how to reference the attribute of an object that is in an array (javascript, Google Apps Script)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a javascript function that creates an array and populates it with objects. Each object has multiple attributes (id, colour, size etc). At the end of the function it sends this array of objects to a Google Apps Script.

When the Apps script function receives this array I want to use a for loop to go through the array and for each object add the attributes of the object into a spreadsheet by appending new rows. I just don't know how to reference the attribute of an object that is in an array while in the for loop.

Code example:

```
/*
the array is structured like this
arrayOfObjects = [
object1
    object1.id = 1
    object1.colour = 'red'
    object1.size = 5
,
object2
    object2.id = 2
    object2.colour = 'blue'
    object2.size = 2

and so on...

]
*/


function appendRowsToSS(arrayOfObjects){
  var url = "myspreadsheetID";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("mysheet");
  
  
    for (i = 0; i < arrayOfObjects.length; i++) {

       //Here I want to get the attributes of each object in the array and append them to a new row
       ws.appendRow([ arrayOfObjects[i].id , arrayOfObjects[i].colour , arrayOfObjects[i].size ]); //Is this how I reference them?

    }

}

//I hope that the first row appended to the ss will be (1 , red , 5) and the next row will be (2 , blue , 2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"Is this how I reference them?"* ... Yes, that is one way. Any errors?

Comment: hi, I haven't tried yet but wanted to check that I wasn't miles off with the referencing. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That is how you reference them.

```
ws.appendRow([ arrayOfObjects[i].id , arrayOfObjects[i].colour , arrayOfObjects[i].size ]);
```

Also, declare `i` in the loop:

```
for (let i = 0;/*..*/)
```